# What is the difference between "topple off" and "topple"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

What is the difference between "topple off" and "topple"?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific and provide us with insights about why exactly are you looking for the difference? Did you read them somewhere and can't understand the meaning of the sentences? In that case, it would be helpful for the fellow learners and answerers to guide you through.

Comment: Have you looked the terms up in a dictionary? https://www.merriam-webster.com/ is a great place to start

Answer (score 3):

To differentiate simply.

A stack of dominoes on the floor could topple if knocked.
A stack of dominoes on a table could topple off if knocked.

To topple off, it first must be **on** something, otherwise it can only topple.

There's a 3rd option, which is to "topple over". This is probably tautological, but people use it anyway. It doesn't differentiate like the previous examples.

Comment: thanks a lot)))

Comment: "topple over" means like "topple off" or "topple" ?

Comment: It means either. As is said, it doesn't differentiate. It only specifies a vague 'direction'… which for toppling always equates to 'down'.

Comment: Arman: topple over means to fall over from the top. Topple off means to fall off something. If you drink too much, you topple over. In other words, your head goes first.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally consider "It toppled off the table" to be a simple verb followed by a prepositional phrase, rather than a phrasal verb "topple off".

It would mean that something "toppled and fell off". I suppose it could be used as a phrasal verb, without an explicit object in sentences like:

> Don't put your cup on the edge of the table, it might topple off.

With the implied meaning "topple off the table".

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary (like [this one](https://www.lexico.com/definition/topple)) will tell you that "topple" can mean either

> **1** [*no object, with adverbial of direction*] Overbalance or cause to
> overbalance and fall.

or

> **2** [*with object*] Remove (a government or person in authority) from power;
> overthrow.

Your question seems to be about meaning **1**.

If you drink too much beer you might *topple over*. Or you might *topple off* the pavement (US: 'sidewalk') into the road. It means you lose your balance and fall down. A dead parrot topples off its perch.